# android sqlite BigDecimal: convert from double or text without loss of precision

Tags: android, sqlite, android-database

create table Foo (productName text, price numeric)

How to convert the price into a BigDecimal in android?

```
new BigDecimal(cursor.getString(1))

or 

new BigDecimal(cursor.getDouble(1))
```

It should not lose precision.

Answer (score 2):

In short the only way to not lose precision is to fool SQlite when saving the data for a NUMERIC column.

Assuming the value value **1234567890.1234567890** SQLite will store this be it a string or a double according to numeric affinity as per :-

> A column with NUMERIC affinity may contain values using all five
>   storage classes. When text data is inserted into a NUMERIC column, the
>   storage class of the text is converted to INTEGER or REAL (in order of
>   preference) if such conversion is lossless and reversible. For
>   conversions between TEXT and REAL storage classes, SQLite considers
>   the conversion to be lossless and reversible if the first 15
>   significant decimal digits of the number are preserved. If the
>   lossless conversion of TEXT to INTEGER or REAL is not possible then
>   the value is stored using the TEXT storage class. No attempt is made
>   to convert NULL or BLOB values.

[Datatypes In SQLite Version 3 - 3. Type Affinity](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Retrieving the value via **`getDouble`** will result in loss of precision, resulting in the Big Decimal being passed a value of **1234567890.1234567165374755859375** (see output below).

Retrieving the value via **`getString`** will result in loss of precision resulting in the Big Decimal being passed a value of **1.23457e+09** (see output below).

#### How to Fool SQLite

A way around this would be to ***fool*** SQLITE, for example saving **MYNUMB=1234567890.1234567890**, will be saved as TEXT and can then be retrieved as the original string, stripped of MYNUMB= and used to set the BIG DECIMAL with **1234567890.1234567890**.

The following code may be of interest or use and was used determining the above :-

#### MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper mydbhlpr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Get DBHelper
        mydbhlpr = new DBHelper(this);
        // Empty table
        mydbhlpr.getWritableDatabase().delete(DBHelper.TBNAME,null,null);

        // Insert value as a string
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DBHelper.PRODUCTNAME_COL,"myproduct");
        cv.put(DBHelper.PRICE_COL,"1234567890.1234567890");
        cv.put(DBHelper.COMMENTS_COL,"DATA INPUT AS STRING");
        mydbhlpr.insertRow(cv);
        cv.clear();

        // insert value as a double
        cv.put(DBHelper.PRODUCTNAME_COL,"myproduct");
        cv.put(DBHelper.PRICE_COL,1234567890.1234567890D);
        cv.put(DBHelper.COMMENTS_COL,"DATA INPUT AS DOUBLE");
        mydbhlpr.insertRow(cv);

        // alternative insert method with value as a string
        mydbhlpr.getWritableDatabase().execSQL(
                "INSERT INTO " + DBHelper.TBNAME + "(" +
                        DBHelper.PRODUCTNAME_COL + "," +
                        DBHelper.PRICE_COL + "," +
                        DBHelper.COMMENTS_COL +
                        ")" +
                        " VALUES('myproduct','1234567890.1234567890','ALTERNATE INPUT STR')"
        );

        // alternative insert method with value as numeric (i.e. not in quotes)
        mydbhlpr.getWritableDatabase().execSQL(
                "INSERT INTO " + DBHelper.TBNAME + "(" +
                        DBHelper.PRODUCTNAME_COL + "," +
                        DBHelper.PRICE_COL + "," +
                        DBHelper.COMMENTS_COL +
                        ")" +
                        " VALUES('myproduct',1234567890.1234567890,'ALTERNATE INPUT NUM')"
        );

        // method to force store numeric data (would need to strip MYNUM= before convert)
        mydbhlpr.getWritableDatabase().execSQL(
                "INSERT INTO " + DBHelper.TBNAME + "(" +
                        DBHelper.PRODUCTNAME_COL + "," +
                        DBHelper.PRICE_COL + "," +
                        DBHelper.COMMENTS_COL +
                        ")" +
                        " VALUES('myproduct','MYNUM=1234567890.1234567890','FOOLIT INPUT NUM')"
        );

        mydbhlpr.retrieveData();
    }
}
```

This basically populates the table (see DBHelper) with 5 rows and then calls the `retrieveData` method to output conversion results to the Log for each row in the table.

#### DBHelper

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "bigdecimal";
    public static final String TBNAME = "bd";
    public static final String PRODUCTNAME_COL = "productName";
    public static final String PRICE_COL = "price";
    public static final String COMMENTS_COL = "comments";


    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DBNAME,null,DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String tblcrtsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBNAME + "(" +
                PRODUCTNAME_COL + " TEXT, " +
                PRICE_COL + " NUMERIC, " +
                COMMENTS_COL + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(tblcrtsql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public void insertRow(ContentValues cv) {
        mDB.insert(TBNAME,null,cv);
    }

    public void retrieveData() {
        String priceasstr;
        Double priceasdbl;
        BigDecimal bdstrprice, bddblprice;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.000000000000");

        Cursor csr = mDB.query(TBNAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            priceasstr = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(PRICE_COL));
            priceasdbl = csr.getDouble(csr.getColumnIndex(PRICE_COL));
            try {
                bdstrprice = new BigDecimal(priceasstr);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("OOOPS","extracted data not a valid number");
                String extracted = priceasstr.substring(6);
                bdstrprice = new BigDecimal(extracted);
            }

            bddblprice = new BigDecimal(priceasdbl);
            Log.d("ROWINFO",
                    "Row = " + Integer.toString(csr.getPosition()) +
                            ". Commentary: " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COMMENTS_COL)) +
                            "\n\tValue extracted as String = " + priceasstr +
                            "\n\tValue extracted as Double = " + Double.toString(priceasdbl) +
                            "\n\t  formatted  from Double  = " + df.format(priceasdbl) +
                            "\n\tBD via getString          = " + bdstrprice.toString() +
                            "\n\tBD via getDouble          = " + bddblprice.toString() +
                            "\n\tBDF via getString         = " + df.format(bdstrprice) +
                            "\n\tBDF via getDouble         = " + df.format(bddblprice)
            );
        }
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
10-05 18:41:18.392 4535-4535/mjt.so46593121 D/ROWINFO: Row = 0. Commentary: DATA INPUT AS STRING
                                                        Value extracted as String = 1.23457e+09
                                                        Value extracted as Double = 1.2345678901234567E9
                                                          formatted  from Double  = 1234567890.123456700000
                                                        BD via getString          = 1.23457E+9
                                                        BD via getDouble          = 1234567890.1234567165374755859375
                                                        BDF via getString         = 1234570000.000000000000
                                                        BDF via getDouble         = 1234567890.123456716537
10-05 18:41:18.392 4535-4535/mjt.so46593121 D/ROWINFO: Row = 1. Commentary: DATA INPUT AS DOUBLE
                                                        Value extracted as String = 1.23457e+09
                                                        Value extracted as Double = 1.2345678901234567E9
                                                          formatted  from Double  = 1234567890.123456700000
                                                        BD via getString          = 1.23457E+9
                                                        BD via getDouble          = 1234567890.1234567165374755859375
                                                        BDF via getString         = 1234570000.000000000000
                                                        BDF via getDouble         = 1234567890.123456716537
10-05 18:41:18.392 4535-4535/mjt.so46593121 D/ROWINFO: Row = 2. Commentary: ALTERNATE INPUT STR
                                                        Value extracted as String = 1.23457e+09
                                                        Value extracted as Double = 1.2345678901234567E9
                                                          formatted  from Double  = 1234567890.123456700000
                                                        BD via getString          = 1.23457E+9
                                                        BD via getDouble          = 1234567890.1234567165374755859375
                                                        BDF via getString         = 1234570000.000000000000
                                                        BDF via getDouble         = 1234567890.123456716537
10-05 18:41:18.392 4535-4535/mjt.so46593121 D/ROWINFO: Row = 3. Commentary: ALTERNATE INPUT NUM
                                                        Value extracted as String = 1.23457e+09
                                                        Value extracted as Double = 1.2345678901234567E9
                                                          formatted  from Double  = 1234567890.123456700000
                                                        BD via getString          = 1.23457E+9
                                                        BD via getDouble          = 1234567890.1234567165374755859375
                                                        BDF via getString         = 1234570000.000000000000
                                                        BDF via getDouble         = 1234567890.123456716537
10-05 18:41:18.392 4535-4535/mjt.so46593121 D/OOOPS: extracted data not a valid number
10-05 18:41:18.392 4535-4535/mjt.so46593121 D/ROWINFO: Row = 4. Commentary: FOOLIT INPUT NUM
                                                        Value extracted as String = MYNUM=1234567890.1234567890
                                                        Value extracted as Double = 0.0
                                                          formatted  from Double  = .000000000000
                                                        BD via getString          = 1234567890.1234567890
                                                        BD via getDouble          = 0
                                                        BDF via getString         = 1234567890.123456789000
                                                        BDF via getDouble         = .000000000000
```